# Why does the default statement works after cases, when i remove c = getchar() part?

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, default

Default statement works when i remove getchar part.

//First version

```
 int c;
 while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    switch(c){

        case 'a': case 'A': printf("aaa"); break;
        default: printf("invalid");

    }
 }
```

//Second version

```
int c;
 while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    switch(c){

        case 'a': case 'A': printf("aaa"); break;
        default: printf("invalid");

    }
    c = getchar();
 }
```

At the first version default part works together with (case a) when i entered a however at the second version it's not the case. Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're getting an input with getchar() repeatedly, you need to clear the input buffer in order to scan another input.

In the first version you posted, `case:'a'` is executed normally, and when the program reaches the end of the while loop, it needs to clear the input buffer. So it performs a scan operation itself (by scanning an empty input) and enters the loop once more.

You can easily clean the buffer at the end of the while loop:

```
int c;
 while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
  switch(c){

    case 'a': case 'A': printf("aaa"); break;
    default: printf("invalid");

  }
  getchar(); // Clear input buffer in order to scan next input.
}
```